# Align label text using an expression

Tags: qgis, labeling, data-defined-override

I want to align text to a specific angle in QGIS. Both the text and the angle are specified in a table (column: street name / column: angle) When I generate the labels, at the moment all the labels are placed horizontal. I want the labels (street name) to align to the specified angle from the angle column.

Any ideas on how to do this? Maybe using an expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to GIS.SE! In QGIS you can control any aspect of labeling (and styling as well) by attribute values or expression, a feature called *data defined override*. Goto **Layer properties | Labels | Placement** and under **Data defined** near Rotation you can select the column / field containing your rotation angles:

[image]