# QGIS Labels Rotation

Tags: qgis, labeling, angles, rotate

I have imported some OS MasterMap data into QGIS 3.2 and have labelled the Cartographic Text dataset. This dataset has a rotation field, populated with various angles of rotation depending where they are to be positioned with relation to roads and buildings. However, when I choose this column under Data Defined Placement, it seems to be rotating the labels in the wrong direction.

Is there a way to tell QGIS to treat the angles differently, as you can in ArcGIS (geographic or arithmetic)?

Comment: Is this stored in a database? you can do angle expressions in the expression builder. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279504/align-label-text-using-an-expression

Answer (score 4):

To use an expression to control label rotation, choose "edit" from the data defined override menu.

[image]

If all of your angles are positive numbers, use this expression to make them negative:

```
concat('-',  to_real('fieldname'))
```

If your angles include positive and negative values, use this expression:

```
 to_real('fieldname') * -1
```

If your field is already in numerical format you can leave out the `to_real()` function.

Comment: i'd also check the field type in the layer properties, if it's a string you may need to convert it to an integer.

Comment: Thanks @StevenKay, I incorporated your suggestion into my answer. I used `to_real()` instead of `to_int()`, in case their angles require decimal place specificity.

Comment: Hi csk. I entered your first expression (concat) and this worked perfectly. Many thanks.